Doctrine updating the timestamp without updating the entity
I have two entities viz WallPost and WallPostLike and they are related by OneToMany relationship.
WallPost.php
#[ORM\Table(name: "wall_posts")]
class WallPost
{
    use UserIdTrait;
    use DistrictIdTrait;
    use ModifiedTrait;

    #[ORM\OneToMany(mappedBy: 'wallPost', targetEntity: WallPostLike::class, fetch: 'EAGER')]
    private Collection $wallPostLikes;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->wallPostLikes = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * @return Collection<int, WallPostLike>
     */
    public function getWallPostLikes(): Collection
    {
        return $this->wallPostLikes;
    }
}

WallPostLike.php
#[ApiResource(
    shortName: 'WallPostLike',
    paginationEnabled: false,
    graphQlOperations: [
        new Mutation(
            resolver: WallPostLikesResolver::class,
            args: [
                WallPostLikeEnum::WALL_POST_ID => ['type' => 'String!'],
                PostParam::CURRENT_SCHOOL_ID   => ['type' => 'String!'],
            ],
            name: 'toggle',
        ),
    ],
)]
#[ORM\Table(name: "wall_post_likes")]
class WallPostLike
{
    use ModifiedTrait;

    #[ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity: WallPost::class, inversedBy: 'wallPostLike')]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'wall_post_id', referencedColumnName: 'id', nullable: false)]
    private WallPost $wallPost;

    public function getWallPost(): WallPost
    {
        return $this->wallPost;
    }

    public function setWallPost(WallPost $wallPost): self
    {
        $this->wallPost = $wallPost;

        return $this;
    }
}

The WallPost Entity has modified column to track the timestamp when entity updates. The problem is the timestamp of modified column is updated when I call toggleWallPostLike API to like a post. The strange thing is the timestamp is already updated even before reaching the resolver function of the requested API.
ModifiedTrait.php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Traits\Entity;

use DateTime;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation\Timestampable;

trait ModifiedTrait
{
    #[Timestampable(on: 'update')]
    #[ORM\Column(name: 'modified', type: 'datetime')]
    private DateTime $modified;

    public function getModified(): DateTime
    {
        return $this->modified;
    }

    public function setModified(DateTime $modified): self
    {
        $this->modified = $modified;

        return $this;
    }
}

To check, whether something is really updated, I have added PreUpdate Lifecycle event in WallPost entity and to my surprise two of the fields viz user_id and district_id of this entity has changes in their value as shown in following image

Here is how UserIdTrait.php looks like for reference
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace App\Traits\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Column;
use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\IdGenerator\UuidGenerator;

trait UserIdTrait
{
    #[Column(name: 'user_id', type: 'uuid')]
    #[ORM\GeneratedValue('CUSTOM')]
    #[ORM\CustomIdGenerator(UuidGenerator::class)]
    private string $userId;

    public function getUserId(): string
    {
        return $this->userId;
    }

    public function setUserId(string $userId): self
    {
        $this->userId = $userId;

        return $this;
    }
}

I am not really sure how doctrine / Timestampable extension works behind the scene but this should not be the desired behavior.
